# Install Tensorflow | Spyder | Python 3.7 Win64

Tags: python-3.x, pip, installation, tensor

How to install tf with spyder/anaconda versions of python (3.7), pip, venv ? (Win10)

I could check that i am running 64-bit python and pip, venv are installed. I downloaded a wheel file from tensorflow website, i intend to run it using pip.

Should i add an address to enviromnent variable `PATH` ? In cmd, `python3` is not recognized, i guess that i am not pointing to the right directory. (I can't find the `Python` directory as it does not appear in `User/appdata/local` where no `Program` folder is to be found.)

TF install guides mentions the creation of a virtual env with

`virtualenv --system-site-packages -p python3 ./venv`

`virtualenv` is not recognized as a command, etc.

Would you like to outline clear step by step guideline to install TF using pip ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would avoid using pip when you are using Anaconda. Try using the Anaconda Prompt that came with the Anaconda Package. 
After that I suggest creating a new environment in Anaconda and install tensorflow using

```
conda create --name test python=3.7 tensorflow
```

Comment: where should i use this command, in cmd ? should i add folders to the `PATH` variable ? thanks!

Comment: When you installed Anaconda it should've came with a separate command prompt called Anaconda Prompt. Search for that on your computer and use the command in that as it has the `conda` commands built in. I didn't do anything related to the `PATH` variable so leave it alone for now. Hope this works!

Comment: not yet: i could install typing in conda shell, though back to spyder, import tensorflow throws an error, tf unknown. I tried command `conda activate test` in conda shell as suggested at the end of install, same error

Comment: I guess that test is the name you give to a new environment, why need to create a new env ?

Comment: The new environment is called test. `conda create --name test python=3.7 tensorflow` creates a new environment called test and installs python and tensorflow. This way nothing should conflict and throw additional errors with other libraries or modules. I usually avoid installing anything on my base environment in case anything goes wrong.

Comment: i don't understand why installing python, it is included in conda ?

Comment: how do i install directly in `base` and not in virtual env ? what would be the cmd line?

Comment: You should be in base when you start the prompt. Then install using 
    conda install tensorflow